# What does it mean to determine all models for a formula $\phi$?

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I am faced with trying to determine all models for a formula $\phi$. I am reading through the book Logic in Computer Science (Huth & Ryan) and I am unable to find what the very meaning of such an expression means.

I might be able to find *a* model $\mathcal{M}$, s.t. $\mathcal{M} \vDash \phi$, but finding all models for $\phi$ seems - hard.

Have I misunderstood something or is it really possible to find all models for a formula?

Comment: Can you provide some more elements, please (like ref to page number...) ?

Comment: The actual problem is not present in the book, but is a more general question. "If I have a formula, how do I find the models for that formula?"

Comment: With reason and experience ... See page 129 : "trying to verify that $φ_1, φ_2,\ldots , φ_n \vDash ψ$ holds, we have to check things out for *all possible models*, all models which are equipped with the right structure (i.e. they have functions and predicates with the matching number of arguments). This task is impossible to perform mechanically. This should be contrasted to the situation in propositional logic, where the computation of the truth tables for the propositions involved
was the basis for computing this relationship successfully."

Comment: Thank you for your pointer, I will look into this and return if I have further questions.

Comment: With insight, you can find counter-examples, i.e. interpretations that "falsify" an invalid formula, like : $\forall x \ \exists y P(x,y) \to \exists y \ \forall x  P(x,y)$

Comment: For *validity*, we have to build up a "semantical" argument showing that e.g. entailments hold, reasoning on "generic" models.

Comment: For example, the conjunction of the axioms for "group" give us  a formula.  All models for that formula are all groups.